# $E_{i,j} = E_{i,r} * E_{r,s} * E_{s,j} (i,j=1,2,...,n)$ where $E_{x,y}$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with a 1 in row x column y and 0's otherwise.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

This matrix equation was given in my ring theory text as a step in showing that there are no nontrivial proper ideals of the ring of $n \times n$ matrices with real number entries.  I am assuming it means THERE EXISTS $r$ and $s$ in $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $E_{i,j} = E_{i,r} * E_{r,s} * E_{s,j}  (i,j=1,2,...,n)$.  Is there a way to prove the equation by constructiong  ${E_r,s}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the context of this is, but the equation is true for any choice of r and s.  (And as I suggest to students, if you don't see why it's true write down an example - eg with 4x4 matrices. It should be obvious!)

Comment: OK, thanks, I tried some examples and in every case what you are stating as being obvious is (to me) amazingly true.

Comment: I don't know if you're still interested, but is this obvious (from the examples): $E_{i,k}*E_{k,p}=E_{i,p}$ ?

Comment: Yes, this part is obvious (at least after observing a few more examples).

Comment: So then $E_{i,k}*E_{k,p}*E_{p,j}=E_{i,p}*E_{p,j}=E_{i,j}$. (associative property) 
(Sorry - I seem to have changed the letters!)

Comment: OK thanks.  Now it seems clear.  In fact, would you agree that E_i,j * E_j,k * E_k,m * E_m,n  =  E_i,n?

Comment: Yup!  (And so on ...)